# What is meant by event i n azure event hub

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-eventgrid, azure-eventhub

I would like to know what is meant by an event in azure event hub.
I thought it's like getting some content(string) from source and process it by other services is one event.
if so, what is maximum content(string) I can send at one event

Answer (score 1):

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas

> Maximum size of Event Hubs event -    1 MB

For Event Hub an event just contains binary payload. How long your string content in there can be depends on the encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16, ASCII...) you chose.